# Approval Process: Sending Notification to Submitter NOT the Approver

Tags: approval-process, notification

According to these resources I found, I believe this is a known issue from Salesforce where Approval Process sends the bell notification to the Quote Submitter NOT the Approver.

[developer salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DOQMQA4)
[Idea Exchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdllUUAR/include-approval-submitted-by-or-approval-submitter-as-notification-recipient)
[Idea Exchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdm3qUAB/notification-to-the-initial-submitter-of-an-approval-process)

Since this issue, in our org, we created a Record Triggered Flow for sending Notifications for the Approval Processes. Now, the first approval request creates the notifications like expected. But, when a second approval request for the same Quote is send, it sends the notification to the Submitter not the Approver again. The notification history does not show any second notification as well.

So my question here is:

- Has anyone found a solution to this issue?
- From winter 21, we can send notifications using Apex. Has anyone done this? Not sure, if this will fix the issue since Flow could not, and the fact that this bug is inherently from Salesforce side.